# Composer's classmap does not recognize classes

Tags: php, composer-php, libraries

I am writing a small application, based on the Slim framework, and occasionally I encountered the need for injecting code retrieved from *phpclasses.org*. Until now, I did it by including each file separately, however as the amount of classes grew, I thought I would go for an autoloader. My folder structure is below:

```
app/
  config/
  core/
  lang/
  libs/ <-- [additional classes]
  models/ <-- [model files]
  views/
vendor/
public/
composer.json
```

My *composer.json* looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "slim/slim-skeleton",
  "description": "A Slim Framework skeleton application for rapid development",

<...>

  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["app/libs/", "app/models/"]
  }
}
```

All other features work without any issues, yet *vendor/composer/autoloader_classmap.php* does not show any signs of adding any classes from *app/libs* or *app/models*. I am using the latest version of composer.phar. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. *vendor/autoload.php* does get loaded at the beginning, before each class call.

P.P.S. I did *php composer.phar dump-autoload*, and also without any luck.

Comment: do the classes have namespaces defined ?

Comment: Not at all, every class is without a namespace.

Comment: Are you are working on OSX which has case-insensitive filesystem by default? they have the same case ?

Comment: Show us at least one of the files that do not appear in the classmap.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the issue directly, but I have forked the repos required and am now using PSR-4 loading method instead. Looks like it was an issue that was directly related to the products provided on [phpclasses.org](http://phpclasses.org).